# SharePoint notification template not including all fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint site whereby whenever a user is assigned an item, they get a notification.

This is done by going to "List Settings" --> "Advanced Settings"  --> "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?"

Unfortunately when the notification is sent, some custom fields are not included in the e-mail.

How do I get all the custom fields included in the e-mail ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple content types in your list or only one content type?

Answer (score 0):

The fields included in the notification email are set in advance.

I suggest you create a flow to send a notification when a user is assigned an item.

Comment: I just added two custom fields. One was included in the notification and the other one was not. How does SharePoint decide which custom fields to include in the notification and which one to omit?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this issue from my end. Whenever I create a new custom column in list, it will be shown in email notification.

Example:

[image]

You can also check my replies on related thread at: [Send e-mail when ownership is assigned not listing IDs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/send-e-mail-when-ownership-is-assigned-not-listing-ids/m-p/3587280)

Comment: What is the data type of column which is not shown in email notification?